# Maximum compress 4 csv files

Tags: linux, tar, filesize, zip

I have 4 csv files with size of 32Mb, 35Mb, 350Kb, 23Mb.

I need a high compression (less than 5 MB) any help what should I do?

I have tried:

```
zip -9 var-log-files-9.zip directory/*
tar cvzf file.tar.gz directory/*
```

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78262/which-file-compression-software-for-linux-offers-the-highest-size-reduction-for.

Also, you may try to use `zstd --compress --ultra -v -22` and `xz -ve9 --compress` they both give much better compression then traditional `zip` and `bzip`.